# Url routing for custom controller in yii

Tags: url, yii

I'm new in yii framework and have a problem with url routing.
I have one controller - StaticPage and actions index (default) and send.
Thats my config:

```
'urlManager' => array(
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'urlFormat' => 'path',
        'rules' => array(
            'call' => 'staticPage/index',
            'call/send' => 'staticPage/send'
        ),
    ),
```

When i try set pattern like this `'call/<_a>' => 'staticPage/<_a>'` i get 404 error, why ?

Comment: Most important - is it apache 404 or yii generated 404?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always put the more specific rules on top. After a rule matches all following rules will not be checked anymore. That means in your case, if you try the URL `/call/send`, the first rule will match and route to `staticPage/index`.

If you want to add `'call/<_a>' => 'staticPage/<_a>'` make this the first rule and remove the `'call/send'` rule.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
'call' => 'staticPage/index',
'call/<action:\w+>' => 'staticPage/<action>',
//or 'call/<action:(send|abc|something)>' => 'staticPage/<action>',
```